# Converting UTF8 characters to slash escaped numeric values

Tags: bash, terminal, unicode, character-encoding

My system language is not Japanese, but my user language/encoding is.
Using shell things in terminal emulators 'directly' works okay, but it seems that 'behind the scene' stuff does not.

```
保存 = Save for example.
```

This gets displayed correctly when I use X stuff 'directly' (as in, I open a terminal emulator or GUI program and mess with it directly)
But running stuff in the background (using dmenu, in the xmonad WM ) it turns out that what gets fed into scripts is not something I can string compare to, but something like this:

```
保存...
```

gets turned into

```
'\344\277\235\345\255\230...'
```

How do I generate this myself? I only got the escaped value string from this by putting a copy paste thing into the script.

I'm fine with doing a pre-pass that translates such an escaped value string into a 'proper' one that then gets case matched later.

I would simply like to generate such an escaped value string myself without the roundabout hack.

Comment: Is it just the characters outside the ASCII range you want to convert or all of them. What should happen for control characters (like TAB, NL) or ``\`` or `'` themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `zsh` shell, with:

```
string="保存 = Save for example.
Also including newlines,
'quotes and \backslashes"

() {
  local LC_ALL=C
  quoted=${${(qqqq)1}#'$'}
} "$string"

printf '%s\n' $quoted
```

Gives:

```
'\344\277\235\345\255\230 = Save for example.\nAlso including newlines,\n\'quotes and \\backslashes'
```

If it's only the bytes over 0x80 you want to convert to `\ooo`:

```
printf %s "$string" |
  perl -l -0777 -pe 's/[\x80-\xff]/sprintf "\\%o", ord$&/ge'
```

would give (from any Bourne-like shell):

```
\344\277\235\345\255\230 = Save for example.
Also including newlines,
'quotes and \backslashes
```